# Error with BiBTeX when compiling

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have some issues using BibTeX for my bibliography. LaTeX keeps having error about this undefined control sequence:

```
! Undefined control sequence.<write> ...subitem}{\@mcitecorrectmaxwidthsubitem} \end{mcitethebibliography}

\end{mcitethebibliography}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I'm trying to use the `achemso` package for my bibliography style, but I don't think that's the problem since I have the same using `plain` or `chicago`... I'm using the `natbib` package as indicated for `achemso`. Note that when I compile without BibTeX, everything's running fine actually.

I'm using JabRef and TeXMaker either on mac (TeXLive) on Windows (MiKTeX).

Thank you very much indeed!

EDIT : Here's my preamble : 
Indeed, i should have done that since the very beginning...
Here's a part of my document :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{m-pictex,m-ch-en}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rsc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\include{partie_1}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Note that in my "partie_1" document, i don't even use

```
\cite{...}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you!
Indeed, i should have done that since the very beginning, i'm editing my question right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some problem with using `achemso` when you do not have any citations. If I run

```
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{library.bib}
\end{document}
```

I get an error. But running

```
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{library.bib}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\begin{document}
\cite{somebody1990}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{library.bib}
\end{document}
```

works fine.

So, if you don't have any citations, delete the bibliography or change the bibstyle

Comment: Thanks for your help, when i add a citation, using the achemso package, i have another error :

    ! Extra \endcsname.
    ! Use of \@mcitecurstatus doesn't match its definition.

Still, when i use another bibstyle, i have the same error occuring...

I just noticed that i have an extra .bib.bak file close to my .bib file... is there any problem with it?...

Comment: So i started again with a fresh one (i deleted all the .aux and stuff files) and took care of adding a ref when compiling et voila, it actually worked pretty well...
Thanks again Rud Faden for your help! =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you were having, am using achemso, and wondered what could be wrong because I had citations in my document. Turns out that putting a space in the name of the LaTeX .tex source file (which is a bad idea anyway) was causing this problem.

```
\documentclass{achemso}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\author{Dylan}\email{jfriend@eng.ucsd.edu}
\affiliation{Making the Band, Detroit, MI USA}
\title{Tapes spit hot fire}
\begin{document}
Look, this is not why I got into the music business to be a sugar cookie
getta.\cite{berndt1988high}
\bibliographystyle{achemso} 
\bibliography{MyPubBib}
\end{document}
```

with MyPubBib.bib as

```
@article{berndt1988high,
Author = {Berndt, H},
Journal = {Fresenius' Zeitschrift f{\"u}r analytische Chemie},
Number = {3-4},
Pages = {321--323},
Publisher = {Springer},
Title = {High pressure nebulization: a new way of sample introduction for atomic spectroscopy},
Volume = {331},
Year = {1988}}
```

saved as `test1.tex` compiles fine, but compilation as `test 1.tex` does not, throwing the `\mcite...` error